# Who is missing here?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, board-games

> It seems my last few puzzles have all been far too easy and quickly solved. Let's see how long this one stands against the genius of the combined PSE community.

---

$$[56\;68\;76\;80\;80\;76\;68\;56]^2 \;\;\;\sum=560$$
$$[26\;38\;52\;52\;52\;52\;38\;26]^2 \;\;\;\sum=336$$
$$[36\;58\;58\;58\;58\;58\;58\;36]^2 \;\;\;\sum=420$$
$$[168\;180\;188\;192\;192\;188\;180\;168]^2 \;\;\;\sum=1456$$
$$[14\forall64] \;\;\;\sum=896$$

---

If you think you know the answer for the above, don't be too hasty. Before writing your answer, consider this:

---

$$\between 1\ \&\ 3$$ 
$$\sec$$
$$\between 2\ \&\ 4$$ 
$$3 \oplus  4 $$
$$\underrightarrow{1}$$
$$\nexists\in\Game\quad\underrightarrow{3}$$

---

And just to clarify: You are seeking the unique and unambiguously defined answer (one word) to the question

> ## Who is missing here?

Comment: This is what happens when we allow one or two rascals to solve puzzles too quickly.  Everyone gets punished.

Comment: *Punished*, you call it?

Comment: Is the change from 5 to 1 in the second block of formulae (or whatever they are) a *correction*? Or does it just make things easier somehow while leading to the same answer?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think it could be seen *both* ways. I realized after making the puzzle that I used a correct, but not so common assumption. The puzzle leads to the identical answer with 1 and the "common" assumption or with 5 and the alternative assumption. The second part, however, only makes sense after a break-through from the first.

Answer (score 11):

<sub>**A “piece” of the puzzle**,
having only inconclusively considered the second part...</sub>

> <sup>If you think you know the answer for the above, don't be too hasty.
>   Before writing your answer, consider this:   . . .</sup>
>   
>   $\require{begingroup} \begingroup
>   \let \BS    = \boldsymbol
>    \let \S    =  \small
>     \let \T   =   \textsf
>      \def \B                  { \color{black} }
>       \def \V #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{ [ #1 ~ #2 ~ #3 ~ #4 ~ #5 ~ #6 ~ #7 ~ #8 ] }
> $

Sorry to have missed you, 
$\S\BS{ \V {7}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{7} \times
         \V{0}{14}{14}{14}{28}{14}{14}{0} }\raise-1ex\strut$, 
perhaps known as 
$\S\BS{ \V {7}{ 7}{7}{7}{7}{7}{7}{7} \times
         \V{0}{16}{8}{8}{8}{8}{8}{0} }$, 
but also known as...

> ...**Pawn**, the chess piece.

Fortunately the [board-games](/questions/tagged/board-games) tag helped us find you!
 
Signed,

> $\S\kern32mu \B{ \V{ 56}{ 68}{ 76}{ 80}{ 80}{ 76}{ 68}{ 56}^2 } \kern32mu$
>  – **Bishop**, the chess piece
>  
>  $\S\kern32mu \B{ \V{ 26}{ 38}{ 52}{ 52}{ 52}{ 52}{ 38}{ 26}^2 } \kern32mu$
>  – **Knight**,   〃
>  
>  $\S\kern32mu \B{ \V{ 36}{ 58}{ 58}{ 58}{ 58}{ 58}{ 58}{ 36}^2 } \kern32mu$
>  – **King**,       〃
>  
>  $\S          \B{ \V{168}{180}{188}{192}{192}{188}{180}{168}^2 } \kern03mu$
>  – **Queen**,    〃
>  
>  $\S\kern88mu \B{            [ 14 \, \forall \, 64 ]           } \kern92mu$
>  – **Rook**,     〃
>  
>  What clicked was that chess is a board game with 6 different pieces,
>  while 5 *not*-missing players are presented in the puzzle,
>  and that an unobstructed **rook** can range over some or another
>  **14** squares from
>  **∀**ll
>  **64** squares of the board.
>   
>  To be sure, this puzzle oozes 8×8-ness,
>  so the [board-games](/questions/tagged/board-games) tag probably would have been
>  unnecessary in the long run.

These formulations represent our...

> ...attack ability (perhaps move ability)
>  summaries from each rank or file,
>  and ultimately square, of a chess board.
>  
>  For example,
>  $\S\BS{ \V{56}{68}{76}{80}{80}{76}{68}{56}^2 }$
>  summarizes the number of squares vulnerable to attack,
>  or that may be moved to,
>  by an unobstructed **bishop**
>  standing in each of the 64 squares:
>
> ```
>  Attack ability of a bishop            Rank         Example of a "9" square
>           __________________________  totals       __________________________
>          |                          |      ]      |                          |
>          |  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  |   56        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  7  9  9  9  9  9  9  7  |   68        |  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  7  9 11 11 11 11  9  7  |   76        |  .  2  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  7  9 11 13 13 11  9  7  |   80        |  .  .  3  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  7  9 11 13 13 11  9  7  |   80        |  .  .  .  4  .  .  .  9  |
>          |  7  9 11 11 11 11  9  7  |   76        |  .  .  .  .  5  .  8  .  |
>          |  7  9  9  9  9 [9] 9  7  |   68        |  .  .  .  .  . [B] .  .  |
>          |  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  |   56        |  .  .  .  .  7  .  6  .  |
>          |__________________________| [           |__________________________|
>  File
>  totals  [ 56 68 76 80 80 76 68 56  ]
> ```

As such, you could be formulated 
$\S\BS{ \V {7}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{7} \times
         \V{0}{14}{14}{14}{28}{14}{14}{0} }$.

> ```
>  Attack ability of                                  Examples of "4" (with en
>  a bottom-homed pawn                   Rank         passant) and "2" squares
>           __________________________  totals       __________________________
>          |                          |      ]      |                          |
>          |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  |    0        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  |   14        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  |   14        |  1  .  2  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  2 [4] 4  4  4  4  4  2  |   28        |  3 [P] 4  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  |   14        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  |   14        |  .  .  .  .  1  .  2  .  |
>          |  1  2  2  2  2 [2] 2  1  |   14        |  .  .  .  .  . [P] .  .  |
>          |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  |    0        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |__________________________|  [          |__________________________|
>  File
>  totals  [  7 14 14 14 14 14 14  7  ]
> ```

Or you could be formulated 
$\S\BS{ \V {7}{ 7}{7}{7}{7}{7}{7}{7} \times
         \V{0}{16}{8}{8}{8}{8}{8}{0} }$.

> ```
>  Move ability of
>  a bottom-homed pawn                   Rank         Example of a "2" square
>           __________________________  totals       __________________________
>          |                          |      ]      |                          |
>          |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  |    0        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  |    8        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  |    8        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  |    8        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  |    8        |  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  |
>          |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  |    8        |  .  .  .  .  .  2  .  .  |
>          |  2  2  2  2  2 [2] 2  2  |   16        |  .  .  .  .  . [P] .  .  |
>          |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  |    0        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |__________________________|  [          |__________________________|
>  File
>  totals  [  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  ]
> ```

**The case for 
  $\S\BS{ \V {7}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{7} \times
           \V{0}{14}{14}{14}{28}{14}{14}{0}  \,}$
  as your formulation**

> A pawn’s formulation of 
>  $\S \V{7}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{14}{7} \times \V{0}{14}{14}{14}{28}{14}{14}{0} \,$
>  is based on *attacking*,
>  which fits the strictest interpretation of king’s 
>  $\S \V{36}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{36}^2 $.
>   
>  A king’s formulation based on *moving*, however, would be
>  $\S \V{36}{58}{58}{58}{\BS{60}}{58}{58}{36} \times \V{\BS{38}}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{36} \,$,
>  because castling is an additional move,
>  without a parallel attack posture.
>
> ```
>  Move ability of
>  a bottom-homed king                   Rank     The "7" square includes castling
>           __________________________  totals       __________________________
>          |                          |      ]      |                          |
>          |  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  3  |   36        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
>          |  5  8  8  8  8  8  8  5  |   58        |  .  .  .  1  2  3  .  .  |
>          |  3  5  5  5 [7] 5  5  3  |   38        |  .  .  4  5 [K] 6  7  .  |
>          |__________________________| [           |__________________________|
>  File
>  totals  [ 36 58 58 58 60 58 58 36  ]
> ```

**Considering, without solving, the second set of clues**

What if the first set of clues were enumerated?

> $\S \def \L  #1#2#3#4{ \B{#1} & \B{#2} & \sf #3 & \T{#4} \\ }{}  \begin{array}{c}{}   \L     {                \T{(missing)}     \phantom{^2} }{0}{P}{pawn}{}    \L    {     \V{56}{68}{76}{80}{80}{76}{68}{56}^2      }{1}{B}{bishop}{}     \L   {     \V{26}{38}{52}{52}{52}{52}{38}{26}^2      }{2}{N}{knight}{}      \L  {     \V{36}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{58}{36}^2      }{3}{K}{king}{}       \L { \V{168}{180}{188}{192}{192}{188}{180}{168}^2  }{4}{Q}{queen}{}        \L{               [14 \forall 64]   \phantom {^2} }{5}{R}{rook}{}\end{array}$
>  
>  $\S\B{\T{New interpretations of the second set of clues}}$
>  $\S\B{\T{would be suggested,}}$
>  $\S\B{\T{without apparent benefit . . .}}$
>  
>   
>  $\S\begin{array}{c|cc}{}  \B { \between   1   ~ \& ~   3  }      &{}   \T{between  B/bishop  &  K/king}      & \T{CDEFGHIJ / N / queen}        ~?{} \\[1ex]{}  \B { \sec                            } &{}   \T{secant of nothing / half of "second"("knight")}{}                                         & ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 \T{ / "kni"} ~~?{} \\[1ex]{}  \B { \between   2   ~ \& ~   4    }    &{}   \T{between  N/knight  &  Q/queen)}    & ~~ \T{OP / K / bishop}         ~~?{} \\[1ex]{}  \B {     3     \oplus        4       } &{}   \T{K(11)/"king"  xor   Q(17)/"queen"} & ~~ \T{Z(26) / "egikqu"}         ~?{} \\[1ex]{}  \B { \underrightarrow{1}                         } &{}   \T{                           bishop moves right} ~???{} \\{}  \B { \nexists\in\Game\quad \underrightarrow{3}    } &{}    \T{not an element of the game , king moves right} ~?{}\end{array}$

**Incidental interpretations of 
  $\S\BS{ \V{56}{68}{76}{80}{80}{76}{68}{56}^2 }$
  dealt out of play along the way**

- Dot product. Too obvious, and more likely written as 
  $\S | 56 ~ 68 ~ 76 ~ 80 ~ 80 ~ 76 ~ 68 ~ 56 |^2 $
  anyway.
- Borders of a square
  (before seeing the [board-games](/questions/tagged/board-games) clue).
   
  An interesting brush with the true solution’s square formation.

  ```
                      56 56 68                                     56 68 76
                      68    76  ?                                  80    80  ?
                      76 80 80                                     76 68 56
  ```
- Outer product, like a multiplication table.
  Eerily suggestive in binary.

  ```
                      56  |  3136  3808  4256  4480  4480  4256  3808  3136
                      68  |  3808  4624  5168  5440  5440  5168  4624  3808
                      76  |  4256  5168  5776  6080  6080  5776  5168  4256
                      80  |  4480  5440  6080  6400  6400  6080  5440  4480
                      80  |  4480  5440  6080  6400  6400  6080  5440  4480
                      76  |  4256  5168  5776  6080  6080  5776  5168  4256
                      68  |  3808  4624  5168  5440  5440  5168  4624  3808
                      56  |  3136  3808  4256  4480  4480  4256  3808  3136
                          |_________________________________________________
                              56    68    76    80    80    76    68    56

  First 4 columns as binary:  ghostly lettering?
        0110001000000     0111011100000     1000010100000     1000110000000
        0111011100000     1001000010000     1010000110000     1010101000000
        1000010100000     1010000110000     1011010010000     1011111000000
        1000110000000     1010101000000     1011111000000     1100100000000
        1000110000000     1010101000000     1011111000000     1100100000000
        1000010100000     1010000110000     1011010010000     1011111000000
        0111011100000     1001000010000     1010000110000     1010101000000
        0110001000000     0111011100000     1000010100000     1000110000000

  Rotated and accentuated:  game pieces?
        ........          .@@..@@.          .@@..@@.          ........
        .@@..@@.          @.@..@.@          @@....@@          ........
        @@....@@          @..@@..@          ...@@...          .@@..@@.
        .@@@@@@.          @......@          @.@@@@.@          @.@..@.@
        ...@@...          ...@@...          ...@@...          @@@@@@@@
        .@....@.          @@....@@          ..@@@@..          ..@..@..
        @@....@@          @.@@@@.@          .@@@@@@.          .@@..@@.
        @@....@@          @......@          ........          ...@@...
        ..@@@@..          .@@@@@@.          @@@@@@@@          @@@@@@@@
  ```

$\endgroup$

Comment: Very good! I knew the 'board game' would be a strong clue, but I guess it was needed. Seeing the connections though is still a remarkable feat. But as the puzzle states... PAWN is not the Who who is missing here ;-) Still holding back my check. (Pun indented)

Comment: (But to be clear: Your answer so far is 'exactly' as intended.)

Comment: Found some [interesting notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_annotation_symbols#Other_symbols_2) to consider

Comment: Wow, *love* the ASCI art! Seems indeed like a self-referencing hint. If only I had known... great find.

Comment: In case you're interested (in your own puzzle), @BmyGuest, I'm working on a new angle for the second set of clues, based on the title "Who is missing here?" The second set of clues represents many missing pieces indeed

Comment: Interesting. I would not have thought the 2nd part of the puzzle to be more challenging than the first...

Comment: It strikes me as odd, that this puzzle (90% done) still has not a definite conclusion. With the break - do you have a new attempt? I'd love to close this down. Hint: Simply start with the (found) names of the pieces and the clues.

Comment: Thank you for the boost, @BmyGuest, I hadn't forgotten, just don't have the necessary concentration nowadays. I will again, but don't mind at all if someone else steps in during the meanwhile and gets the credit.

Answer (score 1):

(Community wiki – please add/correct/improve)

$$\small\begin{array}{clr}
\textsf{Clue} &
\textsf{Direct interpretation}
\\[1ex] \hline
   [56~68~76~80~80~76~68~56]^2         & \textsf{dot product}~=~ 39872 &    1001101111000000_2
\\ [26~38~52~52~52~52~38~26]^2         & \textsf{dot product}~=~ 15056 &      11101011010000_2
\\ [36~58~58~58~58~58~58~36]^2         & \textsf{dot product}~=~ 22776 &     101100011111000_2
\\ [168~180~188~192~192~188~180~168]^2 & \textsf{dot product} = 265664 & 1000000110111000000_2
\\ [14\forall64]                       & \scriptsize \left[
                                      \matrix{ 14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 \\[-.5ex]
                                               14~14~14~14~14~14~14~14 } \right]
\end{array}$$

$$\small\begin{array}{ccr}
\textsf{"...consider this"} &
\textsf{Direct interpretation} &
= ~ ?
\\[1ex] \hline
   \between 1\ \&\ 3    & \textsf{between 1 & 3}     & 2
\\ \sec                 & \textsf{secant of nothing} & 1
\\ \between 2\ \&\ 4    & \textsf{between 2 & 4}     & 3
\\ 3 \oplus  4          & \textsf{3 xor 4}           & 7
\\ \underrightarrow{1}                       &   ?   &
\\ \nexists\in\Game\quad \underrightarrow{3} &   ?   &
\end{array}$$

Comment: If you interpret the first 4 formulas as outer products, everything will be an 8×8 matrix

Comment: The Wiki is a good start. I'll leave this puzzle over Easter, but maybe add a clue afterwards if nothing moves on. And yes, it *is* an obscure puzzle and not-straight-fowards ideas are permitted.

Comment: The other way to get 8x8 matrices out of the first four is to treat each number as 8 binary bits. This leaves the superscripts unexplained, though, and while it also produces some letter-looking things nothing meaningful jumps out at me.